# How to check that ImageInputStream has been closed already?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

In my current project, I use third-party library that manipulates images. In some cases I don't know where did an `ImageInputStream` come from (the source code of the library is proprietary, and I cannot edit that code). But I need to close every stream in order to free resources regardless of theirs origin.

> javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream#close method throws exception
>   when the stream has been closed already.

I'm aware of `((MemoryCacheImageInputStream) ios).isClosed()` trick. But that method has private access level and enforces nasty cast.

I'm also know about another approach: catch `IOException`, check the message and suppress exception (when it's related to closing) or re-throw it (otherwise), like this:

```
try {
    imageInputStream.close();
} catch (IOException onClose) {
    String message = onClose.getMessage();
    if ("closed".equals(message)) {
        // suppress the exception and write to log
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException(onClose);
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to check the state of `ImageInputStream`?

Comment: What third-party library are you using? What does it say about closed and non-closed `ImageInputStream`s? Who should be responsible of closing the `ImageInputStream`?

Comment: I cannot tell you about the library because of NDA, sorry.

In major number of cases the library closes streams by itself. But sometimes it doesn't. And I cannot modify the source code of the library. So I need handle closed/non-closed streams by myself.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the third-party library about closed and non-closed `ImageInputStream` objects? What does it say when the input stream is closed or not?

Comment: `ImageInputStream#read` method already closes the steam after reading. It is not closed if null is returned from `read` method

Comment: Yes, I did. According to the documentation, there two cases. 

The first  is processing of "single" images. You specify an image and get result (all the streams are closed by the library).

The second is batch processing. In that case you specify a list of input images and get list of results. It's up to you to close resources, the library doesn't free them for you (yes, weird design decision - seems that authors strove to give maximum flexibility in batch jobs...)

Comment: Note that invoking `close ()` twice should not be a problem at all: "If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect." (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html)

Comment: @Ros5292 I think you mean `ImageIO#read(ImageInputStream)`.

Comment: @daniu Unfortunately, `javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl#close` does not follow the specification. It throws an `IOException`. Should probably be reported as a JDK bug. Unless the devs argue that the spec means "has no effect on the closeable object".

Comment: @flaz14 If the library has two distinct use cases for this, you should know which one you use right? So you know up front if you need to close the stream or not?

Comment: @haraldK Yes I mean `ImageIO#read`. Thanks

Comment: @haraldK I would like to unify calls to the library as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you everyone for comments and leading questions! I accept the answer given by @haraldK. Since it's the most definite and complete. And reveals the pitfalls. Indeed, it will be better to implement a wrapper once and forever. And then use it in try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to check the state of the stream, you only need to make sure it's not closed more than once. One option is to wrap the `ImageInputStream` in another class, that overrides `close()` to be a no-op in the case the stream is already closed. The nice thing about this, is it will work nicely with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), like this:

```
try (ImageInputStream stream = new CloseableStreamFix(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input))) {
    stream.close(); // Close stream once (or as many times you want)
}
// stream implicitly closed again by automatic resource handling, no exception
```

Unfortunately, the code for `CloseableStreamFix` is non-trivial, so I'm not sure if it counts as "elegant" (usage is though):

```
final class CloseableStreamFix extends ImageInputStreamImpl {

    private boolean closed;
    private final ImageInputStream delegate;

    public CloseableStreamFix(ImageInputStream delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    // The method you actually want to override.
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (!closed) {
            closed = true;

            super.close();
            delegate.close();
        }
    }

    // You have to implement these abstract read methods. Easy, just delegate them.
    // ...except you need to keep the stream position in sync.
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        streamPos++;
        return delegate.read();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int read = delegate.read(b, off, len);

        if (read > 0) {
            streamPos += read;
        }

        return read;
    }

    // In a perfect world, the above should be all you need to do. Unfortunately, it's not.


    // We need to keep the delegate position in sync with the position in this class.
    // Overriding the seek method should do.
    @Override
    public void seek(long pos) throws IOException {
        super.seek(pos); // Don't forget to call super here, as we rely on positions being in sync.
        delegate.seek(pos);
    }

    // Some plugins require stream length, so we need to delegate that.
    @Override
    public long length() {
        try {
            // Unfortunately, this method does not declare IOException like the
            // interface method does, so we need this strange try/catch here.
            return delegate.length();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // It's also possible to use a generics hack to throw a checked
            // exception as unchecked. I leave that as an exercise...
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(e);
        }
    }

    // You may be able to skip the flush methods. If you do, skip both.
    @Override
    public void flushBefore(long pos) throws IOException {
        delegate.flushBefore(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getFlushedPosition() {
        return delegate.getFlushedPosition();
    }

    // You could probably skip the methods below, as I don't think they are ever used as intended.
    @Override
    public boolean isCached() {
        return delegate.isCached();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCachedMemory() {
        return delegate.isCachedMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCachedFile() {
        return delegate.isCachedFile();
    }
}
```

...and while I *think* the above covers all the bases, you should probably test it.

Unless you plan to use lots of try-with-resources statements, you will probably find a simple try/catch (like you already have) more readable. I would extract it as a method like this, though:

```
static void close(Closeable closeable) throws IOException {
    try {
        closeable.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        if (!"closed".equals(e.getMessage())) {
            throw e;
        }
        // Otherwise, we're already closed, just ignore it,
    }
}
```

Just beware that relying on the exception message like this *may* break in future Java releases, should someone decide that a better explanation is needed...

Comment: Instead of extending, you can also create a simple wrapper `Closeable` with a getter for the actual input stream, should make the code much simpler.

Comment: @daniu I considered something similar. But as you need to pass an image input stream (not a `Closeable` wrapper) to the 3rd party library, how can you know if it invoked `close()` on the stream?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create a class that extends `ImageInputStream` and implement your own `isClosed()` method, for example by overriding the `close()` method to set a boolean flag to true when closed.